# The futex facility returned an unexpected error code

Tags: c, multithreading, semaphore

When it is run it returns the futex facility returned an unexpected error code or it aborts or it does both. I am not really sure what is wrong with it. I am pretty sure it has something to do with semaphores. The code here as a nurse and client rendezvous for the distribution of a vaccine.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define NUM_VIALS 30
#define SHOTS_PER_VIAL 6
#define NUM_CLIENTS (NUM_VIALS * SHOTS_PER_VIAL)
#define NUM_NURSES 10
#define NUM_STATIONS NUM_NURSES
#define NUM_REGISTRATIONS_SIMULTANEOUSLY 4

/* global variables */
int vials = NUM_VIALS;
int nurse_station[NUM_NURSES +1];
int nurse_station_in = 0;
int nurse_station_out = 0;
sem_t* vacc_completed[NUM_NURSES];
sem_t* ready_clients[NUM_NURSES];

sem_t mutex;
sem_t vials_sem;
sem_t registration_sem;
sem_t station_full;




int get_rand_in_range(int lower, int upper) {
    return (rand() % (upper - lower + 1)) + lower;
}

char *time_str;
char *curr_time_s() {
    time_t t;
    time(&t);
    time_str = ctime(&t);
    // replace ending newline with end-of-string.
    time_str[strlen(time_str) - 1] = '\0';
    return time_str;
}

// lower and upper are in seconds.
```

This is the nurse thread here the nurse inserts themself into the buffer so that can serve a client.

```
// arg is the nurses station number.
void *nurse(void *arg) {
    long int id = (long int)arg;
   

    //start her shift (i.e., thread gets created)
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: nurse %ld started\n", curr_time_s(), id);

    //walk a random amount of time between 1 and 3 seconds to get a vial of vaccine
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: nurse %ld is walking to get a vial of vaccine\n", curr_time_s(), id);
    //walk(1,3)

    while(1){

        //if there are no more vials, leave the clinic.
        sem_wait(&vials_sem);
        if(vials == 0){
            fprintf(stderr, "%sThere are no more vials so nurse  %ld is leaving the clinic\n", curr_time_s(), id);
            break;
        }
        // decrements the number of vials
        vials=vials-1;
        sem_post(&vials_sem);
        //walk back (again between 1 and 3 seconds)
        //walk(1,3);
        int shots = SHOTS_PER_VIAL;
       //do this 6 times:
        while(shots> 0){
            //indicate to the queue of clients waiting for a station assignment that you are ready for the next client.
            //sem_wait(&station_empty);
            sem_wait(&mutex);
            nurse_station[nurse_station_in] = id;
            nurse_station_in= (nurse_station_in+1)% (NUM_NURSES +1);
            //wait for the client to indicate that they are ready to be vaccinated
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: nurse %ld is  waiting for client to be ready for the vaccine\n", curr_time_s(), id);
            sem_post(&mutex);
            sem_post(&station_full);
            
            sem_wait(ready_clients[id]);
            //give the client a vaccination (which takes 5 seconds to administer)
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: nurse %ld is administering the vaccine\n", curr_time_s(), id);
            //administer();
            sem_post(vacc_completed[id]);
            shots = shots -1;
        }
    }
    //Go back to the 2nd step -- walk to get a vial of vaccine.
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: nurse %ld is done\n", curr_time_s(), id);
    pthread_exit(NULL);

}

void *client(void *arg) {
    long int id = (long int)arg;

    fprintf(stderr, "%s: client %ld has arrived and is walking to register\n",
            curr_time_s(), id);
    // walk a random amount between 3 and 10 seconds to the registration desk.
    //walk(3,10);

    //wait for an opening at the registration desk.
    sem_wait(&registration_sem);
    
    //take a random amount of time between 3 and 10 seconds to register.
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: client %ld is registering\n", curr_time_s(), id);
   // register(3, 10); 
    sem_post(&registration_sem);

    //walk a random amount of time between 3 and 10 seconds to get to the station-assignment queue.
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: client %ld  is being added to the assignment queque\n",
            curr_time_s(), id);
     //sem_post(&station_empty);
   // walk(3,10);

    //wait for station assignment
    
    sem_wait(&station_full);
    sem_wait(&mutex);
    long int new_station = nurse_station[nurse_station_out];

    nurse_station_out =(nurse_station_out+1)% (NUM_NURSES +1);
    fprintf(stderr, "%sL client %ld has been assigned to nurse %ld \n", curr_time_s(), id, new_station);
    sem_post(&mutex);
  

    //walk a random amount of time between 1 and 2 seconds to get to the assigned nurse's station.
    //walk(1,2);
    
    //indicate to the nurse that the client is ready for the vaccination
    sem_post( ready_clients[new_station]);

    //wait for the nurse to complete the vaccination
    sem_wait(vacc_completed[new_station]);
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: client %ld leaves the clinic!\n", curr_time_s(), id);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main() {
    srand(time(0));
    
    pthread_t nid[NUM_NURSES],cid[NUM_CLIENTS];


    sem_init(&vials_sem,0, 1);
    sem_init(&registration_sem,0 , NUM_REGISTRATIONS_SIMULTANEOUSLY);

    sem_init(&station_full,0,0);
    sem_init(&mutex,0,1);

    //creation of nurse threads
    for(int i = 0; i < 1; ++i) {
        sem_t n_ready;
        sem_t c_ready;
        sem_init(&n_ready, 0,0);
        sem_init(&c_ready, 0,0);
        vacc_completed[i]= &n_ready;
        ready_clients[i] = &c_ready;
        pthread_create(&nid[i], NULL, (void *)nurse,(void *)i);
    }

    //creation of client threads
    for(int i = 0; i <6; ++i) {
        pthread_create(&cid[i], NULL, (void *)client, (void *)i);
    }

     for(int i = 0; i < 1; ++i) {
        pthread_join(nid[i], NULL);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
        pthread_join(cid[i], NULL);
    }

    pthread_exit(0);
    return 0;
}
'''

Here, you can see that I use multithreading in orde to accomplish a rendezvous.
```

Comment: This is a lot of code to review. If you can, step through in a debugger to see if you can narrow down where the problem occurs.

Comment: In `main`, `n_ready` and `c_ready` are loop scope so they go out of scope at the end of the loop.  So, doing (e.g.) `vacc_completed[i] = &n_ready;` is not valid. Move them to global/file scope.