# The futex facility returned an unexpected error code. Aborted

Tags: c, multithreading, semaphore

I have two threads a nurse thread and a client thread. The nurse thread is supposed to wait until the client thread is read in order to to vaccinate the client. The client waits until the nurse completes the vaccine. I keep getting this error no matter what I do. I am not sure how to fix it. The indexes are all indexes of nurses, so they should be in the array.

```
sem_t* vacc_completed[NUM_NURSES];
sem_t* ready_clients[NUM_NURSES];
```

Client Thread

```
sem_post(ready_clients[new_station]);

//wait for the nurse to complete the vaccination
sem_wait(vacc_completed[new_station]);
```

Nurse Thread

```
sem_wait(ready_clients[id]);
//give the client a vaccination (which takes 5 seconds to administer)
fprintf(stderr, "%s: nurse %ld is administering the vaccine\n", curr_time_s(), id);
//administer();
sem_post(vacc_completed[id]);
```

Main Intializing of threads

```
    srand(time(0));

    pthread_t nid[NUM_NURSES],cid[NUM_CLIENTS];


    sem_init(&vials_sem,0, NUM_NURSES);
    sem_init(&registration_sem,0 , NUM_REGISTRATIONS_SIMULTANEOUSLY);

    sem_init(&station_full,0,0);
    sem_init(&mutex,0,1);

    //creation of nurse threads
    for(long int i = 0; i < NUM_NURSES; ++i) {
        sem_t n_ready;
        sem_t c_ready;
        sem_init(&n_ready, 0,0);
        sem_init(&c_ready, 0,0);
        vacc_completed[i]= &n_ready;
        ready_clients[i] = &c_ready;
        pthread_create(&nid[i], NULL, (void *)nurse,(void *)i);
    }

    //creation of client threads
    for(long int i = 0; i <NUM_CLIENTS; ++i) {
        pthread_create(&cid[i], NULL, (void *)client, (void *)i);
    }

     for(int i = 0; i < NUM_NURSES; ++i) {
        pthread_join(nid[i], NULL);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_CLIENTS; ++i) {
        pthread_join(cid[i], NULL);
    }

    pthread_exit(0);
```

Comment: `for(long int i = 0; i < NUM_NURSES; ++i) {
        sem_t n_ready;
        sem_t c_ready;
        sem_init(&n_ready, 0,0);
        sem_init(&c_ready, 0,0);
        vacc_completed[i]= &n_ready;
        ready_clients[i] = &c_ready;
        pthread_create(&nid[i], NULL, (void *)nurse,(void *)i);
    }`?!?!  What do you think happens to those semaphores when the loop ends?

Comment: Thank you! I made it a global variable and now it works.

Comment: You have _not_ fixed the bugs outlined in your previous [duplicate] question that would cause UB [undefined behavior]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66881689/the-futex-facility-returned-an-unexpected-error-code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The futex facility returned an unexpected error code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66881689/the-futex-facility-returned-an-unexpected-error-code)